# Using old value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I've change one value in application.properties (accessed in code by class annoted by @ConfigurationProperties), rebuilt module but during running application I see that old value (before application.properties edition) is being used. In "target" directory I see that current value is being stored.
What could go wrong here?

Comment: You haven't cleaned your project before rebuilding, so the old property file remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, things that could go wrong, in no particular order:

- There is a specific profile (like dev, local or prod) in force that uses the old value. In Spring, if `profile` is activated, then the properties defined in `application-profile.properties` takes precedence over the ones with the same name defined in the generic `application.properties`
- There is an application.properties file in your classpath that takes precedence over the one in the target directory/in the jar/war/ear. The one in the target dir is the one with the least precedence.
- You haven't cleaned your project before building

Comment: Cleaning whole project helped. Thank you.